# GameKit peer to peer connection issue. It takes long time to deliver an invitation to another device

Tags: ios, objective-c, p2p, gamekit, gkpeerpickercontroller

I'm using GameKit peer-to-peer connection in my app and I'm experiencing the following issue: when using `GKPeerPickerController` sometimes it takes too long time to deliver an invitation to connect from one device to another. Sometimes devices just don't see each other. What can i do about that? Is it better not to use `GKPeerPickerController` at all and present custom interface?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of app you are trying to make, it may be more beneficial for you to have one device act as a Server and another as a Client. I've noticed from personal experience that having both devices act as Peers can take considerably longer, or just flat out not work.

The only disadvantage with the Server / Client perspective is that your users will have to specifically choose one or the other, and you will have to create your own user interface. But if you can work with that then you'll probably get better results. Good luck!